# Typescript: Extend class with Partial<Type> constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

Using typescript, how do extend the User class using `Partial<User>` as the constructor?

*I am also open to solutions which do not use `Partial`. In this case I am only using the utility type to initialize a blank class. i.e. `new User({})`*

Currently, `AdvancedUser` only has `User` properties, but none of the additional `advanced?:` properties.

```js
export class User {
    first_name: string = ''
    last_name: string = ''
    email: string = ''

    constructor(data: Partial<User>) {
        Object.assign(this, data)
    }
}

export class AdvancedUser extends User {
    advanced?: {
        foo?: string
    }

    constructor(data: Partial<User>) {
        super(data)
    }
}
```

---

The provide code actually works. My project was suffering from a downstream typo reverting my `AdvancedUser()` call back to `User()`.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (this is a link to a web IDE with your code in it)](https://tsplay.dev/Wol18w), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  (Here this means no typos or undefined types, and some example use case to show what is missing) This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: @jcalz The `bar` was replacing a possible type. Updated to `string` now.

Comment: I see that you've accepted an answer to this question already, but I'm still not sure what is wrong with the code you have in the question?  How is it not working for you? What are you missing? How does the accepted answer with an unsafe type assertion solve it?  (`{} as User` is not true, and hard to justify why you'd want to do this)

Comment: @jcalz You're right. When updating my code to the answer, I noticed I had a downstream typo. I'm using Vuex, and my Rootstate was set as `User`. That one typo set me back two days and questioning my abilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am also open to solutions which do not use Partial. In this case I am only using the utility type to initialize a blank class. i.e. new User({})

Instead of having constructors that use `Partial`, you can get the result you want by using the `as` keyword, which in my opinion is much cleaner.

As for the `advanced` property, the reason it's not showing up is because it isn't initialized anywhere (neither inline or in the constructor). Assuming you want to keep it as an optional property, all you need to do is initialize it with `undefined`:

```js
export class User {
    first_name: string = '';
    last_name: string = '';
    email: string = '';

    constructor(data: User) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}

export class AdvancedUser extends User {
    advanced?: {
        foo?: string
    } = undefined;

    constructor(data: User) {
        super(data);
    }
}

const au = new AdvancedUser({} as User);
/* OUTPUT:
AdvancedUser: {
  "first_name": "",
  "last_name": "",
  "email": "",
  "advanced": undefined
} 
*/
console.log(au);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this for using Partial?:

```
interface IUserData {
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  email: string;
}

interface IAdvancedUserData {
  doAdvancedStuff(IAdvancedStuffOptions) : string;
}

class AdvancedUserData implements IUserData, IAdvancedUserData {
  
}
```

your User still accepts data of type Partial, then you pass an AdvancedUserData to your AdvancedUser constructor.